# jQuery: check all checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Consider this scenario:

- `<asp:CheckBoxList>` in a master page.
- the goal is to have all checkboxes in this list to be checked on page load.
- there are many checkbox lists on the page.

The markup:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkSubscriptionType" 
        DataSourceID="myDS"
        CssClass="boxes" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name"  />
```

renders to:

`<input id="ctl00_cphContent_chkSubscriptionType_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphContent$chkSubscriptionType$0" />`

**Question:** how can you use jQuery to check all boxes in this `asp:CheckBoxList` on `document.ready`? I see samples everywhere, but naming convention used by the master page throws off the samples in other places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the naming container, the ID's will be auto-generated and messed up, as you mention.  You can use an attribute filter to select all elements that contain the part that you do know, that is, "chkSubscriptionType".  For example:

```
$("input[id*=chkSubscriptionType]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

The *= means "[contains](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeContains#attributevalue)".

Comment: If the css class is specific to the checkboxes in question, that could be used in the selector as well.

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET's naming conventions are slightly frustrating. You can side-step them by wrapping your element in a span, and giving it a class. You can then use that span.class to focus your selector:

```
$(function(){
  // On dom-ready, all checkboxes in span.names will be checked
  $("span.names :checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
});

<span class="names">
  <asp:CheckBoxList ... />
</span>
```

Comment: BlueRaja, why? `:checkbox` is the short-form of `input[type='checkbox']`.

Comment: Is :checkbox the short form of input[type='checkbox'] or just [type='checkbox']?

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox seems to imply the latter by suggesting input:checkbox instead.

Comment: @mark123 There's only one type of checkbox in HTMl. `input[type='checkbox']`, `[type='checkbox']`, and `:checkbox` are all the same thing.

Comment: @JonathanSampson very good and perfect way, thanks +1 for you.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of asp/php/ruby, etc,  you should be able to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```