# check uncheck all checkbox of checkboxlist using jquery ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i was trying to check uncheck all option of checkboxlist programmatically but my code is not working. here is snippet

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myLink').click(function () {
        $("INPUT[id^='chkFileds']").attr('checked', $('#chkFileds').is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

what is wrong in my code. i want that when user click on check hyperlink then all option of checkbox list will be checked and when click again on the same link then all option of checkbox list will be uncheck. please guide me how to do it. thanks

**UPDATE:**

thanks for ur answer but i am not talking about check rather checkbox list what has many checkbox inside.it looks like....he i am giving the html of checkboxlist

```
<table style="font-weight:bold;" id="chkCountry">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="GB" name="chkCountry$0" id="chkCountry_0">
                <label for="chkCountry_0">UK</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="US" name="chkCountry$1" id="chkCountry_1">
                <label for="chkCountry_1">USA</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is your ID misspelled consistently across all your check boxes? Maybe it should be `$("INPUT[id^='chkFields']")`. In addition, what does `$('#chkFileds')` refer to?

Comment: It's going to be much easier to help if you also include the HTML that this is supposed to work with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: check all checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088468/jquery-check-all-checkboxes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You markup is still missing some of the relevant code needed to answer the question properly, but, assuming that `myLink` is a checkbox, the code below will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#myLink').click(function () {
      $("INPUT[id^='chkCountry_']").attr('checked', $('#myLink').is(':checked'));
   });
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzg8t/).

**Note**: You're code is not working for several reasons. Mainly, your selector, `chkFileds`, doesn't relate to the markup you posted in any way.

**Additional Info:**

Here's a quick rundown of the attribute selector operators:

```
=  is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= starts with
$= ends with
*= contains
```

Comment: i change $("INPUT[id^='chkCountry_']") to $("INPUT[id*='chkCountry_']") and now it is working....thanks

Comment: @Thomas, see edit (additional info section). Unless your markup is incorrect, `^=`, which indicates **starts with** should have worked. Either way, glad it's working.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer and Additional Info, this is the best way I have seen till now to implement a check all functionality in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

If your selectors are correct, and they do seem a bit strange, maybe something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myLink').on('click', function () {
        var check = $('#chkFileds').is(':checked') ? false:true;
        $("INPUT[id^='chkFileds']").prop('checked', check);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/SCJcZ/)

What exactly do you mean by "all" options, you are targeting an ID, and it's unique?

Comment: Since `.is(':checked')` returns a boolean, you don't actually need the ternary operator... `var check = $('#chkFileds').is(':checked');` is sufficient. :)

Comment: @pete - It's the other way around? true is false and false is true. Could have used not or !, but did it that way?

Comment: He's modifying all inputs with an ID that **begins with** "chkFileds", not only a single element with an ID that equals that string. The checked status for each of those elements is set to the checked status of the element with ID `chkFileds`. Taking the inverse of the value doesn't seem consistent with the question.

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i am not talking about check rather checkbox list what has many checkbox inside. it looks like....he i am giving the html of checkboxlist <table style="font-weight:bold;" id="chkCountry">
<tbody><tr>
 
<td><input type="checkbox" value="GB" name="chkCountry$0" id="chkCountry_0"><label for="chkCountry_0">UK</label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="US" name="chkCountry$1" id="chkCountry_1"><label for="chkCountry_1">USA</label></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

Comment: @Thomas, post your relevant HTML in your question, not in comments.